# is_singular() function does not work in mu-plugins

Tags: php, wordpress, multisite

I am not able to selectively disable plugins in mu-plugins folder using the `is_singular()` functions in a conditional. It works with functions such as `is_user_logged_in` etc..

But i need to disable plugin for posts hence trying the `is_singular()` but again it does not work in mu-plugins on a multi site, even if I declare the blog id.

I also tried many version such as `'post' == $post->post_type` still no luck. Any ideas for a working conditional in muplugin for multisite to check for post types? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

**is_singular()** conditional tag checks if a singular post is being displayed, which is the case when one of the following returns true: [is_single()](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/is_single), [is_page()](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/is_page) or [is_attachment()](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/is_attachment). If the $post_types parameter is specified, the function will additionally check if the query is for one of the post types specified.

True when viewing a post of the Custom Post Type portfolio.

```
is_singular( 'portfolio' );
```

Try to add custom post type in condition.

Comment: Yes sure I added the function raw, but in my code I added the post type is_singular( 'post' );

Comment: is_singular( 'post' ) give true when post single page called

Comment: Simply `is_singular()` does not work on multisite in the must use plugins. Hope to get an insight on an alternative code to achieve this from a Wordpress expert. Thanks